# Error Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\[project-name].dll" because it was not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I try to build my ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2019 I get the following error:

Error   Could not copy the file "obj\Debug[Project-Name].dll" because it was not found. Project-name

Comment: You can go to the above path in the visual studio directory and delete the above dll and try to remove it from there. You can build again and see if any other errors are there similar to this. It is because, project is still referenced to the file which is not there anymore.

Comment: I have the same issue as well. It seems to be new in VS2019 (even maybe Update 1 or 2) and it happens for several projects. The same projects on the same machine in VS2017 build just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most probably bug in VS2019.
According to some comments on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/519499/could-not-copy-the-file-objx64debugmanagementexe-b.html it helps to unload and reload the project. It helped for me.

Comment: Now fixed in VS 2019 16.1.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this in VS 2017. A project was saved with ILSpy tool. Deleting `<LangVersion>?</LangVersion>` from the project `.csproj` file fixed that error.

Answer (score 1):

With the shift key select all projects.
Then right click and unload and reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that when I publish the project with `--no-build` I face this issue. Remove that and it will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you're facing this issue with Visual Studio 2022, you should close it and restart VS 2022 in Administrator mode. This did it for me.